# C program running an extra loop

Tags: c

**Write a program that points to the table of values ​​of a given function. The initial value of x changes with step d, until the value ​​of y (which is function of x) become greater than a number c**

I have been trying to solve this task for some time but I always come across the same problem.
The program always throws me one more value.
See code.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
    float x,d,y=0;
    float c;
    printf("Write begin and end of interval: ");
    scanf("%f%f",&x,&c);
    printf("Write step d: ");
    scanf("%f",&d);
    printf("x         y\n");
    while (c>y){
        y=pow(x,2)+(1/sqrt(x+1));
        printf("%.2f   %.2f\n",x,y);
        x+=d;
    }
}
```

This is what program does

```
Write begin and end of interval: 1 5
Write step d: 0.5
x         y
1.00   1.71
1.50   2.88
2.00   4.58
2.50   6.78  -------> this is undesired because y>c
```

Mathematical expression

[image]

Comment: One option is to put a condition on the print: `if (y < c) printf(...);`

Comment: You need to rewrite the code so that it first computes `y`, then tests whether `y` exceeds `c`. If it does, then you need to leave the loop and not print another line. A `while` loop with a condition will not do the job; you need the test inside the loop, after `y` is computed and before a line is printed.

Comment: Please edit your question to includ the output as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `if` statement that checks for y after calculation. Note that you have to change it to `c<=y` if you don't want `y=c` to also not get printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    float x,d,y=0;
    float c;
    printf("Write begin and end of interval: ");
    scanf("%f%f",&x,&c);
    printf("Write step d: ");
    scanf("%f",&d);
    printf("x         y\n");
    while (c>y){
        y=pow(x,2)+(1/sqrt(x+1));
        if(c<y){
            break;
        }
        printf("%.2f   %.2f\n",x,y);
        x+=d;
    }
}
```